# File does not exist, but python is printing filename?

Tags: python, csv

I am using python to merge a number of CSV files.

I use this code to find the CSV files:

```
with open('C:\TODAY.csv', 'w') as f_obj:
    rows = []
    files = os.listdir('C:\RAW\\')
```

I then iterate through files and make a list of the rows using:

```
for f in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.csv') and not fnmatch.fnmatch(f, 'TODAY.CSV'):
        print f
        rows.append(open(f).readlines())
```

I added the `print f` for the sake of debugging.

What happens is this:

I get an error saying `results1.csv` does not exist when trying to do the `rows.append` function however the `print f` does print `results1.csv` and therefore it must exist, and python knows it exists because it can print the filename.

So why, if python can print the filename, does python say on the next line that it doesn't exist?

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Exc.py", line 22, in <module>
        rows.append(open(f).readlines())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'result1.csv
```

Comment: What's the exact traceback you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.listdir` gives a list of file *names*, not of file paths. The file names can be used to open a file only if your program's current directory is already the directory you're listing.

Use `os.path.join` to join the directory path with a file name to give a file path:

```
    rows.append(open(os.path.join('C:\RAW\\', f)).readlines())
```

Comment: I understand the theory behind what you're saying, but I now get this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: @JoeSmart sorry, it's `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

Ref https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

fnmatch only tells you if the given filename matches the given pattern, *NOT* whether a file with that name actually exists.

Try this:

```
for f in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*.csv') and not fnmatch.fnmatch(f, 'TODAY.CSV'):
        print f
        try:
            rows.append(open(f).readlines())
        except IOError:
            print "File didn't exist, skipping"
```

Comment: Fair point, Tom. But in this particular case we know the files exist because we just got them from `os.listdir()`. The real issue here, as ecatmur said, is supplying the correct path to `open()`.

Comment: Yup, was my bad - I saw the initial CSV read and assumed he was opening files named by the first CSV - my fault for not reading the question properly.